# @PreUpdate, @PostUpdate, @PrePersist, @PostPersist, @PreRemove y @PostRemove no funcionan en un @Embeddable para una @ElementCollection con OpenXava

Tags: java, jpa, openxava

En mi aplicación OpenXava tenía una entidad con una colección @OneToMany de entidades para crear una estructura maestro/detalle. La entidad principal, Factura, tiene una propiedad persistente total que quiero actualizar cada vez que el usuario añada, quite o cambie un detalle. La interfaz de usuario generada por OpenXava es esta:

[image: Colección de detalles usando @OneToMany]

El total está en el pie de la columna importe y se actualiza cuando una línea se añade, modifica o elimina. He conseguido este efecto usando un método de retrollamada, específicamente con @PostPersist, @PostUpdate y @PostRemove en la clase de detalle:

Este es el código de mi entidad Factura:

```
@Entity @Getter @Setter
@View(members=
    "anyo, numero, fecha;" +
    "cliente;" +
    "detalles;" 
)
@Tab(properties="anyo, numero, fecha, cliente.nombre, total")
public class Factura extends Identifiable {
    
    @DefaultValueCalculator(CurrentYearCalculator.class)
    @Column(length=4) @Required
    int anyo;
    
    @Column(length=6) @Required
    int numero;
    
    @Required @DefaultValueCalculator(CurrentDateCalculator.class) 
    Date fecha;
    
    @ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    Cliente cliente;
    
    @Stereotype("DINERO")
    BigDecimal total;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="factura", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @ListProperties("producto.numero, producto.descripcion, precioUnitario, cantidad, importe[factura.total]")
    List<DetalleFactura> detalles;
            
    public void recalcularTotal() {
        BigDecimal suma = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        for (DetalleFactura detalle: detalles) {
            suma = suma.add(detalle.getImporte());
        }
        total = suma;
    }
            
}
```

Y este para la entidad DetalleFactura:

```
@Entity @Getter @Setter
public class DetalleFactura extends Identifiable {
    
    @ManyToOne
    Factura factura;
        
    @ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    Producto producto;

    @Required 
    BigDecimal precioUnitario;
        
    @Required
    int cantidad;

    @Depends("precioUnitario, cantidad") 
    public BigDecimal getImporte() {
        return new BigDecimal(getCantidad()).multiply(getPrecioUnitario()); 
    }
    
    @PostPersist @PostUpdate @PostRemove
    private void recalcularTotalFactura() {
        factura.recalcularTotal();
    }
    
}
```

El código de arriba funcionaba correctamente. Sin embargo, lo refactoricé para usar @ElementCollection en lugar de @OneToMany, y que así OpenXava generará una interfaz de usuario donde el usuario pudiera editar los detalles en línea, de esta manera:

[image: Colección de detalles usando @ElementCollection]

Para eso cambié la definición de la colección en la entidad Factura a esto:

```
@ElementCollection
@ListProperties("producto.numero, producto.descripcion, precioUnitario, cantidad, importe[factura.total]")
List<DetalleFactura> detalles;
```

Y refactoricé DetalleFactura como un @Embeddable:

```
@Embeddable @Getter @Setter
public class DetalleFactura {
    
    @ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    Product producto;

    @Required 
    BigDecimal precioUnitario;
        
    @Required
    int cantidad;

    @Depends("precioUnitario, cantidad") 
    public BigDecimal getImporte() {
        return new BigDecimal(getCantidad()).multiply(getPrecioUnitario()); 
    }
    
    @PostPersist @PostUpdate @PostRemove
    private void recalcularTotalFactura() {
        // factura.recalcularTotal(); Ya no puedo acceder a factura
        System.out.println("[DetalleFactura.recalcularTotalFactura()] "); // NUNCA SE IMPRIME
    }
    
}
```

El primer problema es que no tengo acceso a la factura desde DetalleFactura, pero lo peor es que el método recalcularTotalFactura() no se ejecuta nunca. Es decir, los métodos de retrollamada de JPA no se ejecutan en un @Embeddable para @ElementCollection.

¿Se pueden ejecutar los métodos de retrollamada en un @Embeddable? ¿Hay alguna manera de resolver este caso?

Answer (score 1):

Los métodos de retrollamada de JPA son para refinar el ciclo de vida de las entidades. Los objetos embebidos (@Embeddable) no tienes su propio ciclo de vida, sino que su ciclo de vida está asociado a la entidad que los contiene.

La especificación JPA 2.2 dice en la sección 3.5.2:

"Entity lifecycle callback methods can be defined on an entity listener class and/or directly on an entity class or mapped superclass."

Fíjate que no dice nada sobre los objetos embebidos.

La solución es mover la lógica del método de retrollamada desde el @Embeddable a la @Entity contenedora. Para tu caso, por ejemplo, quita el método recalcularTotalFactura() de tu embebido DetalleFactura:

```
@Embeddable @Getter @Setter
public class DetalleFactura {
    
    // ...      

    // QUITA ESTE MÉTODO
    // @PostPersist @PostUpdate @PostRemove
    // private void recalcularTotalFactura() {
    //  factura.recalcularTotal();
    // }
        
}
```

Después marca el método recalcularTotal(), que ya tienes en la entidad Factura, con @PrePersist y @PreUpdate, así:

```
@PrePersist @PreUpdate 
public void recalcularTotal() {
    BigDecimal suma = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for (DetalleFactura detalle: detalles) {
        suma = suma.add(detalle.getImporte());
    }
    total = suma;
}
```

Y la propiedad total se sincronizará exactamente igual que en tu versión anterior con una colección @OneToMany.